# How to display the toast meassage only if checkbox is checked?

Tags: android, android-checkbox, android-toast

I have a `checkbox` in my `activity_main.xml`

and I have the following code:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
        if (!screenOn) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screen is turned ON. Broadcast Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Want to display this toast message only in checkbox is checked
        } else {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to display the `Toast` notification only when the `checkbox` is `checked` otherwise it should not be displayed.

Comment: when you check your checkbox then store value in sharedpreference and then check here..compare your value with stored value if yes then show toast message.

Comment: Do you want to access Checkbox in Service  ?

Comment: Yes. I want to access checkbox in service

Comment: You can't do that because Checkbox is GUI Component which is available  on Activity only.

Comment: @Wizard I tried the above code. But I don't get any toast message if the checkbox is checked or not. No toast message at all.

Comment: @MissNoob can add ur Activity code

Comment: Yes Wizard...Thank You very much... <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CheckBox Chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                    Chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                             Toast.makeText(context, "Screen is turned ON. Broadcast Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Try this this will work fine

Comment: Getting the following error
findViewById: The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type UpdateService

Comment: can you tell me the right way please. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Under onCreate**

```
   mSavePassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    mSavePassword.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**In Onclick**

```
    @Override
  public void onClick(View view) 
   {

    switch(view.getId())
    {

    case R.id.checkBox1:

    Toast.makeText(context, "Screen is turned ON. Broadcast Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
   }
```